# Worker Thread: Disabling the parent form when child form is active in a worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have windows application with two forms FormA and formB.

FormA contains a button `btnGet` which when clicked starts a worker thread as follows

```
  private void cmdGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (pdBackgroundWorker.IsBusy == false)
            {
                pdBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
    }
```

The above worker thread invokes a method which should display `FormB` as follows

```
 private void pdBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
  var _verifyID = new frmFormB();                 
   _verifyID.ShowDialog();
   if (!_verifyID.blnVerified)
   {
     return;
   }
   else { //do something }
 }
```

Now, as `formB` is displayed from worker thread, its parent FormA will still be active even though I used `ShowDialog` method to display `formB`.

Is there a better way to handle this such that when `FormB` is active, FormA should be restricted for access just like `ShowDialog` works for non threaded cases?

Comment: Those forms shouldn't be in the worker thread.  Get the verification before starting the background work.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use SynchronizationContext

here is an example.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var worker = new Worker(SynchronizationContext.Current);
        _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender, e) => worker.DoWork();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_backgroundWorker.IsBusy == false)
        {
            _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext;

    private Form2 form2;

    public Worker(SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext)
    {
        _synchronizationContext = synchronizationContext;
        form2 = new Form2();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        _synchronizationContext.Send(callback => OpenForm(), null);
    }

    public void OpenForm()
    {
        form2.ShowDialog();

        if (!form2.blnVerified)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

from msdn

> The SynchronizationContext class is a base class that provides a free-threaded context with no synchronization.
>   The purpose of the synchronization model implemented by this class is to allow the internal asynchronous/synchronous operations of the common language runtime to behave properly with different synchronization models. This model also simplifies some of the requirements that managed applications have had to follow in order to work correctly under different synchronization environments.
>   Providers of synchronization models can extend this class and provide their own implementations for these methods.

hope this helps :)